# Swift - UITextField padding hides the clear button

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have created a special textField that has a padding on the right hand side (I am using RTL language). It works great, except for the fact it hides the clear button. Any ideas how I can present the clear button on top of the padding view?

```
class PaddedTextField: UITextField {

    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5);

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have direct access to the clear button but you can set its frame and origin:

```
 override func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `super.` functions to overridden functions

```
private let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.5, left: 8, bottom: 0.5, right: 8)

override open func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
   let bounds = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
   return bounds.inset(by: padding)
}

override open func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
   let bounds = super.placeholderRect(forBounds: bounds)
   return bounds.inset(by: padding)
}

override open func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
   let bounds = super.editingRect(forBounds: bounds)
   return bounds.inset(by: padding)
}
```